# Отслеживание смены страницы в react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Как вызывать функцию при переходе на другую страницу в react router dom?
Есть хук `useLocation`, но его нельзя использовать в `class` компоненте. Есть ли другие способы?

Comment: В каком плане отследить?

Comment: @SwaD вызывать функцию при переходе на другую страницу

Comment: Возможно это вам поможет [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70143135/how-to-use-react-router-dom-v6-navigate-in-class-component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70143135/how-to-use-react-router-dom-v6-navigate-in-class-component)